# dynamic .length jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, size, html-lists

I have an unordered list with sub menus.

I have an unordered list and i want to print the number of child list items each list item contains , however, the function I wrote only returns 0.

If I replace `$(this)` with a class or ID then it works fine, however, it then prints the same number for every list item, and I need it to be dynamic, returning the `.length` or `.size()` of each individual list item.

Can you please guide me in the right direction? :)

```
/*atomic mass counter*/
$(document).ready(function(mass){

var atomic = $(this).parent('li').length;

$('.atom').html(atomic);

});
```

the class .atom is a child of each list item so the list looks something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class='atom'></div>
    <ul>
      <li><div class='atom'></div></li>
      <li><div class='atom'></div></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><div class='atom'></div></li>
  <li><div class='atom'></div></li>
  <li><div class='atom'></div></li>
</ul>
```

Here's a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6gzau45r/1/

Comment: what are the expected results? Most in example have no sub menu. Not clear what you are wanting to measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses jQuery's [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate all `li` elements and uses [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to count how many elements (and child elements) with class .atom each `li` has.

```
/*atomic mass counter*/
$(document).ready(function (mass) {

    $("li").each(function () {

        var atomic = $(this).find('.atom').length;

        $(this).find('.atom').first().html(atomic);

    });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/6gzau45r/5/)

The `atomic` count is set to the first `.atom` element of each `li`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look the descendents by using `.children()`. Your solution may look similar to:

```
$(document).ready(function(mass){
    // For each atom div
    $('.atom').each(function() {
        // Calculates the children li
        $(this).html($(this).parent().children('ul').children('li').size());
    });    
});
```

Here is a FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/6gzau45r/6/